# checkboxGroupInput in Shiny (basic)

Tags: shiny

new to R. I have a table
[my data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0H5M.png)

I want the output table to be a list of genes containing terms from the checklist. For example, if I check "ADRF" and "PDRF", I should only see the APOE gene (and others that are shared). I feel like this is simple but I just can't figure it out 0.o You can see I have multiple "attempts" in the "renderTable" section, but none seem to work properly.

```
    ui = fluidPage (
    titlePanel("test title"),
    sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( 
      checkboxGroupInput ( inputId = "data1", label = "tester", 
                           c("AD Risk Factors"= "ADRF",
                             "PD Risk Factors" = "PDRF", 
                             "MSA Risk Factor" = "MSARF", 
                             "DLB Risk Factors" = "DLBRF"))),


  mainPanel( tableOutput("coolplot"))
)
)

server = function(input,output) { 

          output$coolplot = renderTable({

data[data$Present_In == input$data1,]             
#filter(data, Present_In == input$data1) drop=false)
#grepl("input$data1", data$Present_In)
#filter(data, grepl('input$data1', Present_In))

          } ) }

shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

`data[data$Present_In %in% input$data1,]` is probably what you need.

Below is a minimal example using the iris dataset; as I don't have your one:

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage (

    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "checkboxgroup", label = "Species", choices = unique(iris$Species)),

    tableOutput("table_1")

)

server = function(input,output) { 

    output$table_1 = renderTable({

        iris[iris$Species %in% input$checkboxgroup, ]             

    }) 

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```